# CrossListQueryInfo or SPSiteDataQuery equivalent in REST API or CSOM

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, rest, search-api

Is there any equivalent in SharePoint 2013 RESTful API or JavaScript Object Model to either one of the following?

- [CrossListQueryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.crosslistqueryinfo(v=office.15).aspx)
- [SPSiteDataQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I have to write some custom C# code to get it, here what I did:

1. Create an HttpHandler or WCF service (any service you like)
2. Write the C# code the convert the data table to JSON
3. Use that JSON in JavaScript as you want

Here is an example how to get all site collection article pages:

```
const string ArticleContentTypeId = "0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D";
const int PagesListItemplateId = 850;
var camlQuery = String.Format(
                     "<Where>" +
                       "<BeginsWith>" +
                         "<FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/>" +
                         "<Value Type='ContentTypeId'>{0}</Value>" +
                       "</BeginsWith>" +
                     "</Where>" +
                     "<OrderBy>" +
                       "<FieldRef Name='ArticleStartDate' Ascending='FALSE' />" +
                     "</OrderBy>", ArticleContentTypeId);
const string ViewFields =
"<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='PublishingPageImage' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='PublishingRollupImage' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='PublishingPageContent' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='ArticleStartDate' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='FileRef' />" +
"<FieldRef Name='Comments' />";

CrossListQueryInfo crossListQueryInfo = new CrossListQueryInfo();

crossListQueryInfo.Lists = string.Format("<Lists ServerTemplate='{0}' />", PagesListItemplateId);
crossListQueryInfo.Query = camlQuery;
crossListQueryInfo.ViewFields = ViewFields;
crossListQueryInfo.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive' />";
crossListQueryInfo.UseCache = true;

CrossListQueryCache crossListQueryCache = new CrossListQueryCache(crossListQueryInfo);

DataTable siteArticles = crossListQueryCache.GetSiteData(SPContext.Current.Site);
var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(siteArticles);
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
context.Response.Write(response);
```

https://github.com/Devville/Devville.DataService/blob/master/Devville.DataService/Devville.DataService.SharePointOperations/GetSiteData.cs#L171

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not...

> The CSOM does not provide a mechanism for querying data across
>   multiple lists that are not associated by a lookup field. In other
>   words, there is no client-side functional equivalent of the
>   SPSiteDataQuery class. If you need to perform a cross-list query from
>   client-side code, consider creating a list view on the server that
>   performs the list aggregation. You can then query the aggregated data
>   from your client-side code.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx

Comment: I know that for CSOM for 2010 that's why I put RESTful first on my question